# PHP script is saying "invalid password" when I know it's correct

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I'm building an intentionally flawed application for presentation purposes for work. It's left vulnerable to demonstrate improper practices and possibly encourage those who would exploit it to do so. There is ample logging on the server so we're able to see when people poke around. I just need a simple login page that uses a `PHP` script to connect to the `SQL` database. I can verify connectivity through the SQL server logs, however, the script returns and says "invalid password" when I know the password and username I'm inputting are correct.

I have tried swapping bits of code from other resources / what I know and I get `internal error 500`

```
// POST variables
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

// MD5 hash
//$pass=md5($pass);



$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = '$user' AND pass = '$pass'";

// Query Login 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Login validation
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) {
header('Location: landing.html');
}
else {
echo "Wrong username or password!";
}
```

I expect the connection to work, instead, it just throws up my "Wrong username or password!" statement

Comment: If the password in the database is currently hashed, then the issue would be that the submitted password is not being hashed before comparing against the one in the database.

Comment: I am not currently hashing the database at the moment unfortunately

Comment: In that case you may be benefited by echoing `$sql` before sending it off, to see if the inputted password matches the data in the database, and or running the query manually in the database to see if that reveals anything to you.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: @Dharman I appreciate your comments, I will add the exit. As for the vulnerabilities, I am fully aware and that is intentional.

Comment: You're intentionally allowing someone to access every person's login details..?

Comment: @Larnu I think OP didn't make it clear, but he wants to demonstrate security flaws and bad programming practices, instead of building an actual runable application.

Comment: @Larnu The database is not a real one. I am building a honeypot of sorts. It's an internal only project meant to draw malicious-intent folks out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way that your scripts is written is incorrect. To check for a correct username and password, I wouldn't check if there are rows. I understand this isn't real and it's meant to show bad scripting/coding/etc however, this is really bad. The reason why it keeps giving you "Wrong username or password!" is because there are no rows being returned. Try rewriting your script like this:

```
<?php

// Connect to Database Server
$server = "serverName\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "dbName", "UID" => "username", "PWD" => "password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

// POST variables
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE `user` = "' . $user . '" AND `pass` = "' . $pass . '"';

// Query Login
$statement = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

if ($statement) {
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($statement);
    if ($rows === true && $rows >= 1) {
        header('Location: landing.html');
    } else {
        echo "Wrong username or password!";
    }
} else {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```